# SCORM Authoring Tools

Tags: ms-word, scorm

I work for a company that converts operation and maintenance manuals and other information and media we find into online courses. Currently, we use Microsoft Word to create the courses because often times, there is a lot of information and it doesn't fit in PowerPoint slides so we need scrollbars to show the information.

I have been searching for a new authoring tool that is SCORM compliant. I haven't been very successful in my search. Programs like Adobe Captivate will take a lot of time for the other writers to learn and it only offers content in the slide like fashion.

Anyone have any ideas on good SCORM authoring tools or a way to convert Word documents to SCORM. If it is the latter, what would I need to do to create various quizzes and tests throughout the courses?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HunterStone's Thesis](http://www.hunterstone.com/thesis.asp) product.

Comment: Is this still supported? The copyright info at the bottom still says 2007. I am going to test out the trial but I would like to use something that is still supported.