# Seeking SCORM-compliant E-learning Content Generation Tool w/ HTML output

Tags: javascript, html, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

First off, I've been given a very tight deadline (read: measured in minutes) to research this, so my apologies if I am missing any obvious answers (or if I even completely misunderstand what I am asking).

I am seeking an Learning Management System with two requirements:

1) It is compliant with SCORM standards, and generates the necessary meta-data

2) Its output in HTML/JS, and NOT Flash, to be compatible with iOS devices.

So far, I have found [Deltalearn](http://www.deltalearn.com/), and a related thread here, titled [Looking for an elearning tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716056/looking-for-an-elearning-tool), which recommends [Moodle](http://moodle.org/). I am looking into both, but need an answer, likely faster than I will be able to read/teach myself the features of these two offerings.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Dave

Comment: This site is to ask questions about code, not shopping for scripts.

Comment: Would it be better if I reworded it to ask what other coders prefer to use when having to develop to these requirements?

Comment: Usually questions are about solving specific problems, not open-ended "is x better than y" type. Your request is so specific that it's doubtful anyone will be able to answer, sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found a thread on SO titled, [SCORM Authoring Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035942/scorm-authoring-tools) that contained a recommendation called [HunterStone's Thesis](http://www.hunterstone.com/thesis.asp) that seems to fit the requirements above. I think this can be marked as "case closed".

Comment: link broken: bad host name!

Answer (score 0):

If you are building SCORM 2004 content, I would use an IDE called [Trident](http://www.scormsoft.com/trident). Its probably one the best authoring tools I've used when I started to learn SCORM (and still use it today).